# How to calculate time and space complexity of the following function.

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

How to calculate  time and space complexity of following function. 
I have tried but I am getting confused because of recursive function calls.

```
public void readDirectory(File file){
    if(file.isDirectory()){
        File[] folder = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : folder) {
            readDirectory(f);
        }
    }else{
        if(file.getName().contains("(2)"))
            System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Time = O(n)**

- For every level of the folder hierarchy you execute the `for` loop only for the items at that level. If there are total of `n` items (files and folders) in the file system, there's only a part of that number in each folder and all of the items in every folder sum up to `n`. At every level of the recursion you make a **linear** traversing of that level and call the function for every child. After executing for every level you still have linear time because for every level you have traversed in a linear time only a subdivision of all files and all subdivisions sum up to the total number of files.

**Space = O(n)**

- Similarly you have `O(n)` space-complexity because you allocate a single `File` object for every file/folder in the current path. It is actually equal to the maximum depth of folder hierarchy because you keep the `File` objects at every level until the next level recursive call finishes but release them only after that. In the *worst case* the folder hierarchy can be `O(n)` deep - when there is only 1 subfolder and no files in each subfolder. This gives you an `O(n)` space complexity

Answer (score -1):

It's a DFS.
Time complexity is O(n) (you visit every file once)
Space is O(max{|directory|}) for the `folder` variable.

Comment: What does `max{|directory|}` mean?

Comment: size of directory that has the most files

Comment: When you call it on a directory, it will load all files/directories for that directory, then all directories for one its subdirectories, and so on (all before releasing the top-most directory's memory), thus it will be a lot more than the number of files in one directory (unless you meant something else by "size", in which case it will be less than that).

Comment: right, so space should be O(max{nesting-level} * max{|directory|})